# ScrollViewer ContentScroll is missing

Tags: xaml, scrollviewer

my ScrollViewer doesn't work.
scrolling isn't possible.

```
<ScrollViewer>
 <StackPanel>
   <ListView>  </ListView>
   <Grid>      </Grid>
   <ListView>  </ListView>
 </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

i have tried different possibilities with setting of height (for ScrollViewer and StackPanel).

how to scroll the content ?

EDIT: VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" and CanContentScroll="True" already used

jeff

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you have your scrollviewer inside something like a stackpanel. Try a grid instead.