# Cannot set ScrollUnit or ContentScroll in Windows Store App

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a VirtualizingStackPanel with Horizontal orientation. I am looking for a way to make the ScrollViewer scroll to content rather than by pixel.
I know that .NET 4.5 brought the ScrollUnit property, however I can't find it on WinRT. There's no ContentScroll too.

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150697/scrollviewer-contentscroll-is-missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListViewBase` has a [`ScrollIntoView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.scrollintoview%28v=win.10%29.aspx) method which is what you would use to scroll to items. You could simply scroll with that to any given item in your list control.